# Simple String Equation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 2 string, say textfield.text and [textArray objectAtIndex:i]
They contain the same string (and tested by NSLog).

//this returns a false

```
if (textfield.text == [textArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

//this returns a true

```
[textArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:textfield.text];
if (textfield.text == [textArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

//this is also true

```
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:[textArray objectAtIndex:i]])
```

Why is the first one returning a false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an == on pointers like NSString * it is comparing memory addresses, not comparing the value of strings.

Your first example:

```
if (textfield.text == [textArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

Is comparing two different memory address. Since they are not the same memory address, the answer is `false`.

Your second example:

```
[textArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:textfield.text];
if (textfield.text == [textArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

Here you have assigned the memory address of `textfield.text` into `[textArray objectAtIndex:i]` thus making them the same memory address. Therefore, the memory addresses are the same so the result is `true`.

Your last example:

```
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:[textArray objectAtIndex:i]])
```

Is the correct way to evaluate two strings regardless of memory addresses because `isEqualToString` compares the value of the strings and not their memory addresses.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting the idea. Can you tell me some uses of comparing memory addresses?

Comment: The overwhelming use I can think of is to see if the two items (pointers) are in fact the same object and not just the same value. If the two pointers have the same memory address then they are referring to the same object. Sadly, I can only think of a real world analogy. If you and I both have "the same" electronic gadget. While they look feel and act the same way, the serial numbers would be different. This would determine which gadget is which, even though they appear identical. The memory address of the object is like it's serial number independent of it's value.

Answer (score 4):

The `==` operator tests if both references point to the same object, not if the strings are equal.  Use `isEqualToString:` if you want to compare the string contents.

Comment: You can't use dot notation that way.

Comment: Changed to an upvote. Just want to make sure that typos don't get recognized as the true answer. Normally I would edit the question myself, but I wanted to be sure that it was just a typo. No hard feelings, eh? ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (textfield.text == [textArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

is an equality (not logical equality sorry). You can't use that for strings.

```
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:[textArray objectAtIndex:i]])
```

However isEqualToString is the equivalent of the statement above. Specifically for strings.

Comment: it would be something like if (i == 5) { do something in code } which would be true if you declared or made the variable i equal 5 beforehand for instnace int i = 5; or i = (some math formula); or another example would be if (i == TRUE) { do something in code } it would enter the statement only if i (BOOLEAN Type) is set to TRUE

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, have you added the object to the array yet??

As a side note, you cannot compare your `NSStrings` with `==`. You should use `isEqualToString:` for that.